# Are node_modules folder files included in build folder of NextJS?

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I am trying to cache my application's(built using NextJS) build folder on CDN but not sure if node_modules are copied in build folder.
Tried searching on internet but could not find any information.
Can anyone share some insight on this please?

Comment: Short answer is yes. But the builder should only copy what is needed and not the whole node_modules

Comment: @grekier where does it copy exactly? can not find under my application's build folder.

Comment: That would depend on the setup. I'm no expert on those build tools but, as I understand it, they will only move files that are imported. There are also some tools to remove unused code from there but, as I said, that would depend on your setup and I'm no expert

Comment: I think that, by default, it would be part of a chunk.js file

Answer (score 0):

Node modules are included in a production build, although not in raw form. The normal node_modules folder includes not only the plain Javascript files required to run the website but also raw source code and some helper files, along with some build tools depending on what libraries you download.

The production build system looks for the called code, bundles it together and minifies it, producing a few, big and very cryptic .js files that are ultimately deployed on the web server. This includes not only your code, but it also processes code imported from node_modules.

In the end, the build folder and all its contents is the only thing you need to deploy and what you can put in cache. It has your site's code and also any dependencies you used. The raw node_modules folder won't be there.